# how to run playframework FunctionalTest through Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, playframework

and the second question:

is it possible to run them all in a bunch through Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FunctionalTest and UnitTest extend BaseTest, which is annotated with the PlayJunit4TestRunner, so you should find that you can just run tests as you would with any other test (i.e. Run As > Junit Test). You'll see the Play environment being initialised on the console before the tests actually run.

One problem I've found is that running a whole package of Play tests in Eclipse is buggy, so I tend to just run one at a time in Eclipse and then use Play's own testrunner to verify the whole suite.

Comment: the problem is i'm using playframework 1.1 - there is no PlayJunit4TestRunne

Comment: I think the PlayJunit4TestRunner class doesn't have any specific 1.2 changes, so I seem to remember it's possible to grab it from the repo and use it along with 1.1.  Otherwise, 1.2 has a whole ton of improvements to Play, so upgrading is advisable if at all possible.

Comment: unfortunately there _is_ changes and it's impossible to simply pick it and use.

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be, Install ['antify'](http://www.playframework.org/modules/antify) module and run 'play antify' on your application. It will create a build.xml for your app (which would import the needed targets from application-build.xml file) and run 'auto-test' from eclipse.